# .NET Compact Framework - multiline text in items

Tags: c#, .net, listview, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there any free available ListView based control for .NET CF that allows multiline text in items/rows?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDF (community edition is free) has the ListBox2, which can be owner-drawn.  [Here's an example](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/PermaLink,guid,418e2e48-09f7-4b10-a57e-a5e32b70b4b9.aspx) that shows multi-line, including different fonts on each line as well as an image in the item too.